# center multiple bootstrap columns when less than 12 col

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="row">
    <div ng-repeat="tile in tiles" class="col-md-3"></div>
</div>
```

How can I make sure that these bootstrap columns are always centered, even if there is only 2 of them?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add `row-center` class to the row and `col-center` to col-md-3 in this way:

```
<div class="row row-center">
  <div ng-repeat="tile in tiles" class="col-md-3 col-center"></div>
</div>

.row-center {
  text-align:center;
}

.col-center {
  display:inline-block;
  float:none;
}
```

[**Bootply Demo**](http://www.bootply.com/40vltts35C)

Answer (score 12):

Starting from bootstrap 4

this feature added!

you can use this class: `justify-content-center`

so your code should looks like:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-4">
      One of two columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      One of two columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Check bootstrap documentation:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#horizontal-alignment